# How to pass mutiple partition keys while querying cosmos?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a scenario where I will receive a comma separated string with multiple ids. These ids are basically partition keys of the container.

Now let's say if I just want to query cosmos with one id then I do the following where I can pass partition key in `.WithPartitionKey`:

```
// With one Id
public async Task<MyTable> GetExistingDocumentsAsync(string myPartitionKey, bool withNoTracking, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // assume that myPartitionKey = "123" 
    var query = withNoTracking ? _dbContext.MyTable.AsNoTracking() : _dbContext.MyTable;
    
    return await query.WithPartitionKey(myPartitionKey).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.myPartitionKey.Equals(myPartitionKey), cancellationToken);
}
```

But when I receive multiple IDs, then how to do that? I want to query cosmos as efficiently as possible.

```
public async Task<MyTable> GetExistingDocumentsAsync(string myPartitionKey, bool withNoTracking, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Assume that myPartitionKey = "1,2,3,4"  
    var query = withNoTracking ? _dbContext.MyTable.AsNoTracking() : _dbContext.MyTable;
    
    // create an array like this: ["1", "2", "3", "4]
    var ids = myPartitionKey.Split(",").Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    var records = new List<MyTable>();

    using var feedIterator = _dbContext.Database
        .GetCosmosClient()
        .GetContainer(DbGlobals.SchemaName.ToLower(),  nameof(MyTable).ToLower())
        .GetItemLinqQueryable<MyTable>()
        // .WithPartitionKey() // How to pass partition key here when it is array
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.myPartitionKey))
        .ToFeedIterator();
    
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var document in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            records.Add(document);
        }
    }
   
    return records; // This has all the records
}
```

Questions:

- Is this efficient/correct way to query with N IDs?
- If no, what is the best practice?

Comment: Take a look at `WHERE... IN...` and `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` - maybe these will help, as it lets you have multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large amount of data (Primary Keys), One solution is to create multiple parallel queries, one for each partition key using `Task.WhenAll`.

Something like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyTable>> GetExistingDocumentsAsync(string myPartitionKey, bool withNoTracking, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var partitionKeys = myPartitionKey.Split(",").Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
    var records = new ConcurrentBag<MyTable>();

    await Task.WhenAll(partitionKeys.Select(async partitionKey =>
    {
        using var _dbContext = new MyDbContext();

        var query = withNoTracking ? _dbContext.MyTable.AsNoTracking() : _dbContext.MyTable;

        using var feedIterator = _dbContext.Database
            .GetCosmosClient()
            .GetContainer(DbGlobals.SchemaName.ToLower(), nameof(MyTable).ToLower())
            .GetItemLinqQueryable<MyTable>()
            .Where(x => x.myPartitionKey == partitionKey)
            .ToFeedIterator();

        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            foreach (var document in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                records.Add(document);
            }
        }
    }));

    return records;
}
```

In your implementation `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.myPartitionKey))`  would take some time and would be a leader to performance issues.

Comment: Bug here that you assume that EF `DbContext` is multithreaded. It is not.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv if so, he could create new `DbContext`.   instance inside `Task.WhenAll`. , but i don't think it is correct approach

Comment: *but i don't think it is correct approach* - what does it mean? It will crash immediately otherwise.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are right, edited the answer.